# Banning a string of emojis

Tags: javascript, discord.js

How do I ban a string of `emojis`? like this:

```
:regional_indicator_n: :regional_indicator_w: :regional_indicator_o: :regional_indicator_r: :regional_indicator_d:
```

I have already banned the `n word` but some users can `bypass` it by using `emoji` letters

```
if (message.content === ":regional_indicator_n: :regional_indicator_w: :regional_indicator_o: :regional_indicator_r: :regional_indicator_d:")
{
    message.delete();
}
```

The code above doesn't work

Comment: Don't you want to check for **one of** the words, rather than the whole sequence? Also, does `message.content` contain other strings?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to remove any of the substrings you listed from your `message` string. If so, you can easily do this with the [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method.

Here, we are searching for any substring starting with `:regional_indicator_`, followed by one of the letters `n`, `w`, `o`, `r`, `d` (the `|` symbol means "or") and ending with another `:`. If such substring is found, it is replaced by an empty string, effectively removing it.

The `/g` flag in the pattern tells the regex to make a global search on the string.

```js
let message = "Foo Bar :regional_indicator_n: Baz";
message = message.replace(/:regional_indicator_(n|w|o|r|d):/g, "");

console.log(message);
```

Comment: This should work (not for the exact sequnce of course). Just a note for @Hedphelym – you probably want/need to check more Ɗs than emoji regional indicators. Unicode is big. http://www.unicode.org/Public/security/latest/confusables.txt